# How can I select an element with a certain exact text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know :contains() could be used to select all elements that contain the specified text. but is there a way to find an **exact** match ?

What I mean is using `jQuery(':contains(josh)')` will also apply to nodes with joshua or joshephin. Is there a way to find out a specific text?

Comment: you can use a combination of `contains()` and `filter()` : `$(':contains(josh)').filter(function() {
  return ($(this).text() == 'josh')).doSomething();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no exact `Content Filter` in jQuery but you should be able to mimic this using this code:

```
$(":contains(josh)").filter(function(){ return ($(this).text() == "josh") })
```

Reference: From the [jQuery .filter() API doc](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> **.filter( function(index) )** A function used as a test for each element in the set. this is the current DOM element.